# How to navigate from a Karate step in .feature file to its corresponding implementation code?

Tags: karate

How to navigate from a Karate step in .feature file to its corresponding implementation code ?
Usually control+left-click should navigate, however, in case of Karate, this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of Karate as like Cucumber, please don't. The whole point of Karate is that you should not need to look at the step-definition (Java) code any more.

If your intent is to debug, refer to the following options in order:

1. The [JUnit dev-mode report](https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report)
2. The [Debug helper](https://github.com/intuit/karate#ide-support)
3. The [Karate UI](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI)
4. If you refer the doc on [troubleshooting IDE support](https://github.com/intuit/karate#troubleshooting-cucumber-ide-support) this may make the "navigate" you refer to start working

Comment: How do I know the implementation of each step in the backend ?

Comment: @SreeCharanShroff read  the source code: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/StepDefs.java